# How can I fix the 'end of non-void function' for my minimum coins owed in change?

Tags: c, recursion, cs50

The problem is to find the minimum number of coins owed given an amount of dollars in change, assuming that available coins to give back are 25c, 10c, 5c and 1c.

I implemented a solution with recursion in C, but somehow it kept throwing the "error: control may reach end of non-void function". I'm fairly new to C so I couldn't quite figure out whats going on. 
Any help is greatly appreciated! Here's my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 

int processChange(float change){
 int centsChange = round(change*100);
 int arr[4] = {25,10,5,1};

  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    int numCoins =0;
    int remainder = centsChange%arr[i];
    if(remainder==0){
        numCoins = (centsChange - remainder)/arr[i];
        return numCoins;
    }


    if(centsChange ==1){return 1;}//base case
    if(centsChange>=arr[i]){
       numCoins = (centsChange - remainder)/arr[i]+ processChange(remainder/100);
        return numCoins;
    }


   } 
}

 int main(){
   float change;
    do
    {
        change = get_float("Enter the changed owed\n");
    }while (change<0);

   printf("Minimum number of coins returned is %d\n", processChange(change));

}
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't use floats for money at all, rather use `int` for *cents*...

Comment: it requires me to input a dollar amount (i.e, $9.75)

Comment: well, given that this is cs50 I guess it is passable. But the question is: what will your function return if the for loop ends?!

Comment: it's supposed to return the number of coins

Comment: no, the execution of the function ends as soon as return is encountered, or the end of function is reached. But you do not have `return` at the end of the function. Also I am not sure the logic is correct, because you zero the `numCoins` on each iteration.

Comment: You return in your if statements. What do you return if none of the ifs satisfy? That's where your problem is.

Comment: @MFnx: It is not possible for none of the `if` statements to be satisfied over the course of the loop. When `i` is three, `arr[i]` is one, `centsChange % arr[i]` is zero, `remainder` is zero, `if (remainder == 0)` is true, and `return numCoins` is executed.

Comment: It's okay to use floating point numbers to help with input and output of money values, but convert to an int type immediately after input and to a floating point immediately before output, so that all the actual math is done in integer types. Floating point types just have too many surprises and aren't meant for things that can be represented with complete accuracy.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes you are right, and you know it, and I do as well. But does the compiler? Hence the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the `for` loop in `processChange` does this:

- If `remainder` is zero, do a calculation and return.
- If `centsChange` is one, return.
- If `centsChange` is at least `arr[i]`, do a calculation and return.
- Otherwise, reach the end of the `for` loop and continue iterating.

As far as the compiler can tell, the value of `i` will reach four, and control will leave the `for` loop. At that point, control would flow to the end of the function, where there is no `return` statement. Thus, the compiler is warning you that control would reach the end of a non-void function. (A “non-void function” is one with a return type that is not `void`. The return type of `processChange` is `int`.)

One way to fix this is to insert a `return` statement at the end of the function.

Another is to disable compiler warnings for this situation, which you can do with GCC and Clang using the `-Wno-return-type` command-line switch.

We can see that control cannot actually leave the `for` statement because, when `i` is three, `arr[i]` is one, so `centsChange % arr[i]` necessarily produces zero, which is assigned to `remainder`, causing code to flow into the first case above. With GCC and Clang, you can inform the compiler of this by inserting `__builtin_unreachable();` as the last statement in the function. That tells the compiler that that point in the code logically cannot be reached by any combination of circumstances within the program. (Using this compiler feature when it is not true that control cannot reach the location will break your program.)

Note that the fact that control cannot leave the `for` loop for the above reason implies the `centsChange == 1` base case is unnecessary. The fact that `remainder == 0` **must** be satisfied at some point means it serves as a base case.

Although this analysis discusses the code as it is, experienced programmers would restructure the code so that none of the above solutions are necessary. There are times when various complications motivate us to use code where the compiler cannot deduce that a certain point is never reached in execution, but we know it is, and the above workarounds may be used in such cases. However, this is not one of them. This code is fairly simple and can be restructured so that control flow is simpler and more apparent to the compiler.

Comment: thank you for your advice. When I tested with the input 0.41, it returned 1, while the right solution is supposed to be 4.  I'm not sure what I did wrong here...

Comment: @ChuChu: In `processChange(remainder/100)`, both `remainder` and `100` are `int`, so an integer division is performed. When `remainder` is 16, the result of `16/100` is zero. You need to perform a floating-point division instead.